# How to show all text in this ternary plot?

Tags: r, ggtern

I have made a ternary plot like this but I cannot see all labels in this plot. What should I do?

[image]

Here is my code

```
tern <- ggtern(data = Triangle2, aes(x = Bulk.soil, y = Rhizosphere.soil, z = Root)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=row.names(Triangle2)), color='black',size=3, check_overlap = FALSE)+
geom_point(aes(size = Relative_abundance,
shape = Shape,
colour = Root_specific),alpha=0.8) +
scale_shape_manual(values = c(19, 19)) +
scale_size_area(max_size = 7,breaks=c(1,10)) +
scale_colour_gradient(low = '#f8766d', high = '#00ba38') +
theme_bw() + theme_showarrows() + theme_nogrid() +
theme(tern.axis.text=element_text(colour="black"),legend.position      = "bottom",
legend.box.just      = 'left')+
guides(shape= "none",
size = guide_legend(order   =2),
colour = "none") +
labs(size = 'Relativeabundance (%)')+labs(x="Bulk", y = "Rhizosphere", z = "Root")+theme(legend.title=element_text(size=10),legend.position = c(0.75,0.75),legend.key=element_blank())+guides(size=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour="darkgrey")))
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try with `ggrepel::geom_text_repel()` https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/

Comment: It showed "Removing Layer 2 ('GeomTextRepel'), as it is not an approved geometry (for ternary plots) under the present ggtern package. " @Phill

Comment: That's disappointing. You can just do something like `geom_text(...., hjust = -0.2, vjust = -0.2)`

Comment: Apart from the technical issue: is the row number your labelling the points with relevant for the viewer anyway? If you "only" want the chart to look up conspicuous cases during the exploration yourself, a small font size on a large printout might be a quick fix.

Comment: Yes this quite help. but I can just see the labels of one side of the triangle by moving label locations. Howeve, I can find the points that did't show in my original plot. Thanks! @Phill

Comment: Actually I just want to which points are concentrated in which part of the triangle. I think change the plot to large printout might help. But how to do that? I try to change the text size of labels but it did not help. @ I_O